# Can we use JAX-WS to generate web service clients for TIBCO

Tags: soap, jms, jax-ws, tibco

In my project I am using a wsdl provided by TIBCO to generate web service client classes. These clients are responsible to to consume TIBCO web services over SOAP/JMS.

I see that the designer has made a comment in design doc like this:
TIBCO jms bindings are proprietary, so standard tools liek JAX-WS , JAX-RPC cannot be used to generate clients. Hence Spring Web Services will be used to generate the clients.

What does this mean?  The designed is no logner with the team. I have no way of asking him

Answer (score 1):

[Standard SOAP binding to JMS](http://www.w3.org/TR/soapjms/) defines a set of JMS properties that can be then used by the toolkits like JAX-WS or JAX-RPC to send the SOAP over JMS. E.g. SOAPJMS_requestURI, SOAPJMS_soapAction, SOAPJMS_contentType, etc.

The developer has probably not followed all the requirements stated in the standard and e.g. already existing endpoint that produces the SOAP requests might not set all the required JMS properties when sending a JMS message, or it might require different set of JMS properties to be set for messages that it consumes.

Spring-WS is probably more flexible when it comes to such customizations and not so picky when processing received messages thus it was recommended by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

At the time the TIBCO code was written, there was no standard for SOAP over JMS ([A W3 recommendation for SOAP over JMS](http://www.w3.org/TR/soapjms/) was released just over a year ago) and all SOAP over JMS bindings were proprietary.

All this really means is that some tools will not understand the bindings and you will need to configure them yourself manually. Other tools will understand the bindings and will automatically configure the bindings in the client. Try it with different frameworks and see how you go.